# SwiftUI Image update breaks animation

Tags: image, animation, swiftui

I have a HStack with an image and a text, forming a basic checkbox. When the toggle state changes and the image is updated, if the position in the container is updated (by removing the view below) the animation doesn't work properly, as shown in the gif. If the image is constant, it works fine (image moves with the text).

The problematic view:

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
    configuration.label
}
```

[image: Result]

I tried changing the toggle state inside `withAnimation` and all combinations of adding `transition` and `animation` modifiers to the image, the whole view or the container view, nothing works. Is there a way to make the Image move with the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.drawingGroup`:

```swift
HStack {
    Image(systemName: configuration.isOn ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
    configuration.label
}
.drawingGroup() // <- HERE
```